# auto-resize for vue echarts is not working

Tags: vue.js, resize, autoresize, echarts

I have tried chart using Echart library.when i try to resize page the chart is not resizing .I am using auto-resize attribute

```
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@4.1.0/dist/echarts.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-echarts@4.0.2"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@4.1.0/dist/echarts.js"></script>
```

```
 <div id="app">
   <v-chart :options="polar" auto-resize/>
 </div>
```

Comment: Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with [this, read How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It's `autoresize`.

Comment: What does this autoresize attribute do and how does it work?

Answer (score 11):

instead of `auto-resize` use `autoresize`

Comment: Ah, brilliant! That's what I needed!